# Insert into table some data where the id = something

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How insert into some table some data where id = (for example) 1

```
INSERT INTO users(value1,value2,value3,value4) VALUES(4,85,17,4) WHERE id=6
```

When i do this i get a syntax error :

> Fatal error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>       corresponds  to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
>       'WHERE id=6' at line 1 in directory on some line

Comment: Are you sure you really want to insert instead of update?

Comment: I am doing a simple social network this page continue filling the needed information like the age or the country this columns are empty i can't update an empty column

Comment: Well... Your question suggests that you intend to do an update... Coz an insert query is not accompanied by a WHERE... Therefore the error....

Comment: Everything is working fine thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert a new record having the same data as an existing one:

```
INSERT INTO users (value1,value2,value3,value4) 
select value1,value2,value3,value4
from users 
WHERE id = 6
```

To update exsting record with `id=6`:

```
UPDATE users
SET value1 = 4,
    value2 = 85,
    value3 = 17,
    value4 = 4
WHERE id = 6
```

Comment: But where i put the value of the columns ?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot `INSERT ... WHERE`. You can `UPDATE ... WHERE`, or `INSERT` a new one with the Id you want.